# How to delete all the characters after one character in the String?

Tags: java, string

I have a String which contains a date, for example "01-01-2012", then an space and then the time "01:01:01". The complete string is: "01-01-2012 01:01:01"

I would like to extract only the date from this string so at the end I would have "01-01-2012" but don't know how to do this.

Comment: Have a look at [codingbat](http://codingbat.com/) - it provides a lot of short exercises to get used to the language :)

Answer (score 41):

Four options (last two added to make this one answer include the options given by others):

- Parse the whole thing as a date/time and then just take the date part (Joda Time or `SimpleDateFormat`)
- Find the first space using `indexOf` and get the leading substring using `substring`:

  ```
  int spaceIndex = text.indexOf(" ");
  if (spaceIndex != -1)
  {
      text = text.substring(0, spaceIndex);
  }
  ```
- Trust that it's valid in the specified format, and that the first space will always be at index 10:

  ```
  text = text.substring(0, 10);
  ```
- Split the string by spaces and then take the first result (seems needlessly inefficient to me, but it'll work...)

  ```
  text = text.split(" ")[0];
  ```

You should consider what you want to happen if there *isn't* a space, too. Does that mean the data was invalid to start with? Should you just continue with the whole string? It will depend on your situation.

Personally I would probably go with the first option - do you really want to parse "01-01-2012 wibble-wobble bad data" as if it were a valid date/time?

Comment: text.substring(0, spaceIndex+1);

Comment: @Ademiban: Why would the OP want to keep the space at the end? That seems unlikely to me.

Comment: text = text.split(" ", 2)[0]; <== is faster

Answer (score 13):

```
String input = "01-01-2012 01:01:01";
String date = d.split(" ")[0];
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
String date = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" "));
```

Or even (because the length is fixed):

```
String date = s.substring(0, 10);
```

Or use [`StringUtils.substringBefore()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringBefore(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
String date = StringUtils.substringBefore(s, " ");
```

Comment: @Ademiban: nope, looks like my version (without `+1`) is correct, I guess we don't need the trailing space after date.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of ways to do this, a very simple method is to split the String at the space and use the first part (which will be the date):

```
String dateTime = "01-01-2012 01:01:01";
String date = dateTime.split(" ")[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and take only the relevant `String` in your resultng `String[]` [in your example, it will be `myString.split(" ")[0]`

Answer (score 1):

In that case where only one space is in the string, you can use `String.split(" ")`. But this is a bad practice. You should parse the date with a [DateFormat](http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/)
.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) to extract the date only:

```
 String thedatetime = "01-01-2012 01:01:01";
 String thedateonly = thedate.substring(0, 10);
```

You should really read through the javadoc for String so you are aware of the available functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you know in advance this is the format of the string, I'd do this:

```
public String getDateOnly(String fullDate){
    String[] spl = fullDate.split(" ");
    return spl[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it either using string manipulation API:

```
String datetime =  "01-01-2012 01:01:01";
int spacePos = datetime.indexOf(" ");
if (spacePos > 0) {
   String date = datetime.substring(0, spacePos - 1);
}
```

or using regular expression:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4})");
String datetime =  "01-01-2012 01:01:01";
Matcher m = p.matcher(datetime);
if(m.find()) {
   String date = m.group(1);
}
```

or using `SimpleDateFormat`

```
DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date date = fmt.parse(datetime);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(date);
String date = c.getDayOfMonth() + "-" + c.getMonth() + "-" + c.getYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.substring(int, int)`. If you are interested in the value of the date and time, then use `SimpleDateFormatter` to parse your string.

Answer (score 0):

`myString.substring(0,10);`

If your string is always in that format (2 digits, minus, 2 digits, minus, 4 digits, space etc...) then you can use `substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)` method of string to get what you want.
Note that second parameter is the index of character **after** returning substring.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explode the complete date from the string use this method.

```
/**
 * @param dateTime format string
 * @param type type of return value : "date" or "time"
 * @return String value
 */

private String getFullDate(String dateTime, String type) {
    String[] array = dateTime.split(" ");
    if (type == "time") {
        System.out.println("getDate: TIME: " + array[1]);
        return array[1];

    } else if (type == "date") {
        System.out.println("getDate: DATE: " + array[0]);
        return array[0];
    } else {
        System.out.println("NULL.");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Otherwise if you want only the date for explample **01**-01-2012

use this:

```
/**
 * @param datetime format string
 * @return
 */
private String getOnlyDate(String datetime) {
    String array[] = datetime.split("-");
    System.out.println("getDate: DATE: " + array[0]);

    return array[0];

}
```

I hope my answer will help you.

Comment: Please explain why your solutions works and also provide comments for better understanding.